# Is ArgumentCaptor changing the value of a generated field?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have an object with a field **id**, that is a generated UUID:

```
id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

I use this in a method where I save the object:

```
saveObject(SomeObject someObject) {
    someRepository.saveObject(someTestObject.id, //other fields)
}
```

But when I use ArgumentCaptor in my test:

```
verify(someRepository, times(1)).save(ntCaptor.capture());
aasertThat(ntCaptor.getValue(),
    allOf(
        hasProperty("id", is(someObject.getId),
        // other fields
    )
```

I get a different id that I save. Is this a bug or is there a different approach to capture generated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this:

```
saveObject(SomeObject someObject) {
    someRepository.saveObject(someTestObject.id, //other fields)
}
```

maybe because you are not using the someObject, you are using someTestObject.

Comment: You know what, I'll give it to you, it was my mistake all along

Comment: thanks bro, you people are the reason who keep motivating us.